# Missing 'Printing' Extension for GeoServer 2.5.2 — Alternative Sources?

Tags: geoserver

I'm currently following the book "Mastering GeoServer" and working on GeoServer version 2.5.2 for a specific project requirement. I'm trying to install the "printing" extension but am unable to find it in the usual places. The book refers to a link **ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.5.x/community-latest/** which seems to be outdated or inaccessible. Does anyone know where I could find the printing extension compatible with GeoServer 2.5.2? Previously, I was using GeoServer 2.7.x on a Windows environment, but I've switched to this older version to align with the book and deepen my understanding using ubuntu 22.04.
Any help would be appreciated.

**What I tried:**

1. followed the book **Mastering GeoServer** to work with GeoServer 2.5.2 for my project.
2. The book directed me to download the **printing** extension from **ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.5.x/community-latest/**.
3. I navigated to the website but was unable to find the printing extension or it seemed the URL was outdated.
4. I attempted to search for alternative sources online, including browsing the GeoServer official website and community forums, but couldn't find the specific version I need (2.5.2).

**What I Was Expecting:**

1. I expected to find the "**printing**" extension readily available for download from the URL given in the book.
2. Alternatively, I expected to find the extension or similar modules in the GeoServer community or official site compatible with version 2.5.2